# PHP Strict Standards errors on localhost

Tags: php, apache

I keep receiving strict standards errors on my local machine (mac os 10.8) when I am trying to install RoundCube.

I tried turning them off by editing the php.ini line to this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

After restarting Apache, all of the error messages still get displayed

I am using the php installer found here at http://php-osx.liip.ch/

When I run phpinfo() the php.ini location is set to here /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

This is the file that I have been editing but no changes I make there appear to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run phpinfo in the same dir (and possibly) script causing one of those errors. it's possible for a php .ini override to be present in multiple places. other .ini file, .htaccess or http.conf php_value, ini_set, etc...

Comment: make display_errors=off in php.ini file

Comment: possibly there's a local htaccess file that's overriding the php.ini settings?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file present in the directory. Running phpinfo() produces the same php.ini file location. Error reporting according to phpinfo() is 30711.

Comment: @VikasUmrao display_errors is set to off but the changes in the php.ini do not appear to be taking hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer script in Roundcube overrides the settings in your php.ini.

I searched the Roundcube folder for files that use the "error_reporting" php function and indeed you can see in .\installer\index.php how the php error level is changed (line 42):

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL&~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Try changing the error level here!